# How to specify a handle of another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to drag a bunch of objects with one handle, and only one object containing the handle. Objects have the same parent, but it seems the handle can only drag a straight parent of itself, but not ‘uncle’.

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/Z5yeW/43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is exactly what you wanted, but here is something to check out: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5yeW/44/

EDIT:
Reverse version: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5yeW/46/

Comment: Thanks, it _may be_ the solution, but can you do it in another way — so div ‘that want be draggable too’ was initially shown on the full height (same height as ‘just draggable’ has) and while moving ‘just draggable’ the visible height of the other ‘that want be draggable’ was decreasing making orange space growing and growing from down to top and full height? Sorry for my English, hope you understand

Comment: Nah, stupid me, that was simple. So the question is ‘how to make it work with revert?’ //updated the fiddle

Comment: Updated my answer with automatic revert version.

Comment: Aww, thank you so much! I was trying to do that with custom `reverting()` function for a long time and already asked that several times with no luck. Thank you!